# PostgreSQL server won't stop

Tags: postgresql, macos, terminal

Having a bit of an issue with PostgreSQL on Mac OS X 10.8.4. I accidentally did `brew rm postgresql --force` while the postgres server was running. When I installed using `brew install postgresql` and ran `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start` I get:

```
pg_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway
server starting
FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists                                                                       
HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 752) running in data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres"?
```

when I run "ps -ef | grep postgres" I get:

```
501   752   235   0 12:42PM ??         0:00.01 /usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres -r /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log
501   754   752   0 12:42PM ??         0:00.00 postgres: checkpointer process       
501   755   752   0 12:42PM ??         0:00.34 postgres: writer process       
501   756   752   0 12:42PM ??         0:00.02 postgres: wal writer process       
501   757   752   0 12:42PM ??         0:00.01 postgres: autovacuum launcher process       
501   758   752   0 12:42PM ??         0:00.01 postgres: stats collector process       
501   945   452   0 12:58PM ttys000    0:00.00 grep postgres
```

when I try to stop the server with `pg_ctl stop -D /usr/local/var/postgres -m fast` or `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop -mi` I get:

```
waiting for server to shut down........................................... Failed
pg_ctl: server does not shut down
```

**EDIT**

```
which pg_ctl
/usr/local/bin/pg_ctl
pg_ctl --version
pg_ctl (PostgreSQL) 9.2.4
```

Gist of `server.log`: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6106182

Comment: Does `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop -m immediate` get any further than the other two attempts?

Comment: That would be the same as running `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop -mi` and yeah all I get is "Server does not shut down"

Comment: I guessed that, but a quick glance at `postgres --help` didn't immediately show the "m" flag.

Comment: `brew reinstall postgresql` https://stackoverflow.com/a/39781473/6086226 worked for me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

turns out that my brew.plist for postgres needed to be unloaded and removed at ~/Library/LaunchAgents/ . After a restart all is well... closing question.

Comment: please expand on this

Answer (score 188):

Had same issue, `pg_ctl: server does not shut down`. Furthermore, `ps auxwww | grep postgres` showed no postgres running, while `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres status` showed that postgres is running. Restarting my mac didn't help, i even went as far as to reset SMC, but this SO Q/A gave me an idea what to look for next: brew issues.

Following this line of thought, i found this helpful [blog post](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/starting-and-stopping-background-services-with-homebrew), that came down to following commands that solved this issue for me:

```
$ brew services list
$ brew services restart postgresql
```

Hope this will help someone.

**Update - Unknown command: services**

After a bit of investigation following one of the comments ('Unknown command: services'), i found out that the authors of Homebrew decided to remove `services` from the repo, seeing as no one wants to maintain this code.

You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/32006) and [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/28657) (related github tickets).

After some more digging, I found [this](https://github.com/gapple/homebrew-services) repo that adds `services` on macs.

This is how I 'returned' `services`:

```
~ » brew tap gapple/services
~ » brew services
usage: [sudo] brew services [--help] <command> [<formula>]

Small wrapper around `launchctl` for supported formulae, commands available:
   cleanup Get rid of stale services and unused plists
   list    List all services managed by `brew services`
   restart Gracefully restart selected service
   start   Start selected service
   stop    Stop selected service

Options, sudo and paths:

  sudo   When run as root, operates on /Library/LaunchDaemons (run at boot!)
  Run at boot:  /Library/LaunchDaemons
  Run at login: /Users/user/Library/LaunchAgents
```

Here is another suggested solution: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/150300/need-help-using-homebrew-services-command. Didn't check it myself, so don't know if and how it works.

Comment: This obsoletes so many bash aliases I've accumulated over the years for doing the exact same thing.  Good look!

Comment: @naturalc updated my answer in response to your comment. tell me if it works ok for you.

Comment: For any Rails users out there, I was trying stop Postgres via usual Rake command, `bundle exec rake pg:stop`.  But that wasn't working, leading to `pg_ctl: server does not shut down`. The workaround `brew services restart postgresql` worked for me. 

Comment: Thanks, man! I couldn't figure that it was actually a homebrew service running. Nice one!

Answer (score 74):

`$ brew services list`

`$ brew services stop postgresql`

*Stopping `postgresql`, but it might take a while
 → Successfully stopped `postgresql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql)*

Comment: Tried stopping with `pg_ctl ... stop` with no avail. Once I ran brew services stop postgresql, my pg_ctl...stop works as expected again now. Not sure how, but I'm glad this solved it!

Comment: I needed to add the version with it. 
`brew services stop postgresql@10`

Answer (score 47):

I was having the same problem...removing the launch agent solved the problem for me:

```
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

Comment: This is spot on. the standard homebrew stop service command refused to work.

Comment: This worked for me, while `brew services stop postgresql` and `brew services stop postgresql@10` didn't work for me.

Comment: Same, using brew kept failing and using DBngin did not help. But removing the launch agent worked ! Thanks

Answer (score 17):

I had a similar issue. I had forgot that I integrated 'lunchy' a few days ago and was using 
it as a launchctl wrapper to initiate plist `~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist` on start up. pg_ctl was not effective because of the following line of code `<key>KeepAlive<key>`:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     2 <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
     3 <plist version="1.0">
     4 <dict>
     5   <key>KeepAlive</key>
     6   <true/>
     7   <key>Label</key>
     8   <string>homebrew.mxcl.postgresql</string>
     9   <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    10   <array>
    11     <string>/usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/postgres</string>
    12     <string>-D</string>
    13     <string>/usr/local/var/postgres</string>
    14     <string>-r</string>
    15     <string>/usr/local/var/postgres/server.log</string>
    16   </array>
    17   <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    18   <true/>
    19   <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    20   <string>/usr/local</string>
    21   <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    22   <string>/usr/local/var/postgres/server.log</string>
    23 </dict>
    24 </plist>
```

Trying to kill the process directly didn't work because I needed to unload the plist.

```
    launchctl unload homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

Comment: Note the .plist file might not have the exact same name.  In my case it was `homebrew.mxcl.postgresql92.plist`.  Check yoself.

Answer (score 12):

I got round this error by using the command

```
pg_ctl stop -m immediate

pg_ctl start
```

I did not need to unload the plist this way.

Comment: I get pg_ctl: no database directory specified and environment variable PGDATA unset

Comment: getting the same error:  no database directory specified and environment variable PGDATA unset

Comment: @SuperUberDuper You should add -D and specify the db location.

For example:
pg_ctl stop -m immediate -D .

"." stands for the current directory, assuming you are on the database directory

Answer (score 9):

When relying on brew-installed PostgreSQL, the following command worked for shutting it down.

```
> brew services stop postgresql

stopping `postgresql`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `postgresql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql)
```

As mentioned in another answer grepping through the list of processes and then killing anything postgres-related does **not** work.

```
ps aux | grep postgres
kill $PID
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have `postgres` started via `brew services`, so couldn't stop it that way.

This worked.

```
$ ps -ef | grep postgres
501   547     1   0  2:07pm ??         0:00.29 /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/bin/postgres -D /Users/username/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-9.6 -p 5432
```

Use `-D` paramater from above.

```
$ pg_ctl stop -D "/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-9.6"
```