# Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.2.dylib

Tags: postgresql, psql, libreadline

I just installed posgresql with homebrew and when I go on to type the command

```
psql
```

I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.2.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/psql
Reason: image not found
[1]    69711 trace trap  psql
```

Does anyone have any idea about what's wrong?

Comment: Looks like it linked to readline, but it's not present. Did you uninstall readline afterwards? How *exactly* did you install PostgreSQL with homebrew? (Steps, commandS).

Comment: Likely solved by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42356309/mac-psql-readline-library-not-loaded/42377043 which has a more succinct answer than most of the below (you probably don't need to reinstall postgres!)

Answer (score 390, accepted):

I was getting the exact same error, but the above answers didn't work for me. I had to reinstall postgresql.

`brew reinstall postgresql`

Comment: This one did it for me on El Capitan

Comment: This was the only one that worked, I tried all the other answers in this page.

Comment: It seems this problem occurred after I installed RVM / Ruby.

Comment: My issue seems to have been related to python installation using brew

Comment: Be careful doing this if you aren't already on the latest version of Postgres. You'll need to reinstall the old Postgres alongside the new one and then do a `pg_upgrade`

Comment: This is very heavy handed if you don't want to lose your local databases.  I had luck with 'brew switch readline 6.3.8'

Comment: BE VERY CAREFUL - reinstall removes the previous version of postgres and if you haven't previously backed up your database for the upgrade process, then you're going to have to install the previous version alongside the new version just to perform the data upgrade.  See here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/upgrading.html  Better to install the new version rather than reinstall it

Comment: If you think re-installing psql is a radical step for what seems like a small bug, you're not alone. This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41476592/839876 seems to address the real problem that most of these answers work around.

Comment: That worked for me aswell. So brew install doesn't work, but reinstall does.. Wierd.

Comment: Worked for me, 2019-01-15, when getting a similar message when trying to use the Heroku pg psql cli.

Comment: Can do this for a specific version too ex: `brew reinstall postgresql@9.5`

Comment: Wow, this worked for me to. I never run DB's locally for anything other than development purposes, and as such, not critical to keep all of my stuff. So it was a simple fix to do this. I highly recommend listening to the warnings in this thread though. Edit: After double checking, I lost no databases or saved info, but still, read the warnings...

Comment: Work for me on Mojave (and another program, `tig` not postgresql)

Comment: Just upgrading  postgres to the latest version that uses the updated readline fixed this for me: `brew upgrade postgres`

Comment: this IS very heavy handed and should possibly NOT be the top answer

Answer (score 135):

The key problem is that your postgresql was trying to find the `libreadline.6.2.dylib` but your `readline` is version `7.0`, so only 7's lib is linked.

I don't think upgrading postgresql is a good idea, it's not easy and may cause a lot of problem, especially when you already have database data.

What I do, is to switch the version of `readline`. When you check `brew info readline`, you will find different versions, mine is `6.3.8`, so I switch to that version by executing:

```
$ brew switch readline 6.3.8
```

It will change to 6.3.8 and create the link:

```
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.3.8
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/readline/7.0.1
Opt link created for /usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.3.8
```

In this case, all the linked lib becomes to 6 version, and command line works:

```
$ ls /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/
libhistory.6.2.dylib    libhistory.dylib    libreadline.a
libhistory.6.3.dylib    libreadline.6.2.dylib   libreadline.dylib
libhistory.6.dylib  libreadline.6.3.dylib
libhistory.a        libreadline.6.dylib
```

However, if you have different apps using the different version of readline, I think you should consider upgrading.

---

**Update: 06/02/2019**

**What if the old version is not installed?**

`Homebrew` doesn't provide a way to install old version formula. And since v2.0.0, it will run `brew cleanup` as default behaviours every 30 days. Therefore, you may accidentally update `brew` and delete the old version.

Here are the steps to install old version:

1. Go to `homebrew-core` directory:

```
    $ cd $(brew --repository)/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core
```

2. Check the hash for old Formula:

```
    $ git log master -- Formula/readline.rb
```

3. Find the corresponding version of the hash value

```
    commit 1dd4221c35716d6bec363ad3425ef93ffe7d9b9f
    Author: BrewTestBot <brew-test-bot@googlegroups.com>
    Date:   Wed Aug 15 21:51:16 2018 +0000

        readline: update 7.0.5 bottle.
```

4. Checkout to old formula:

```
    $ git checkout 1dd4221c35716d6bec363ad3425ef93ffe7d9b9f Formula/readline.rb
```

5. Reinstall the formula:

```
    $ brew reinstall readline
```

6. Reset the repo

Following those steps, you can reinstall the old version of formula.

Comment: And me - if you have no other dependencies on readline 7 then this is definitely the least disruptive approach.

Comment: this worked for me also, saved me from updating postges

Comment: Worked for me too...much cleaner solution than updating the whole databse

Comment: When would one want to switch back to whatever other version of `readline` that was installed? What other downsides are there to doing this?

Comment: I only have one readline installed, and my local checkout of readline only contains 8.0, and the log doesn't have any older version commits, even after fetching everything. Looks like it's impossible to install an older version of readline for me, and upgrading postgres may be the only option

Comment: Using the steps to install an older version doesn't seem like it'll help for installing versions older than 7.0.5 as that's the oldest version mentioned in any commits touching the *readline* formula.

Answer (score 79):

If the situation is you have a higher version readline say 7.0. You can do this

```
cd /usr/local/opt/readline/lib    
ln libreadline.7.0.dylib libreadline.6.2.dylib
```

Comment: I had to create link named "libreadline.6.dylib" but this was the only suggestion that worked for me.

Comment: This in conjunction with `brew uninstall --force gawk` and then `brew install gawk` was what got me up and running.  You might also be able to just `brew reinstall --force gawk`

Comment: Good one. I am running postgres 10.6 which expects libreadline.7.dylib but I had just installed `pg_top` which upgraded libreadline to 8.0 and broke psql. I used your trick, except made it a symlink  `ln -s libreadline.8.0.dylib libreadline.7.dylib`

Comment: Excellent, thanks. This worked on MacOS Mojave without having to uninstall and re-install PostgreSQL (which would have been a real pain).

Answer (score 46):

If you don't have readline installed, first install it:

`brew install readline`

For me, I was getting this error, even though I had readline installed.  Reinstalling readline did the trick:

```
brew reinstall readline
```

Comment: reinstalling readline didn't do it for me, but uninstall/install `bash` did: `brew install --build-from-source bash`

Comment: I found that I had to remove all verison of readline first (brew uninstall --force readline). After I reinstalled it, I had to force link it with "brew link --force readline"

Comment: Reinstalling bash was the fix for me, too, but in my case the "referenced from" line mentioned bash specifically.

Comment: After installing MacOS Sierra, I had been encountering this issue.  I did both `brew reinstall readline` (to get the Sierra-specific brew) and while at it,  `brew reinstall postgresql94`.  People said to reinstall bash but I never had it to begin with.  So this answer and the chosen answer both worked for me.

Comment: brew reinstall readline worked for me after switching to other versions (which has worked in the past) no longer worked after upgrading to psql9.6

Answer (score 32):

This worked for me

```
brew switch readline
```

This would display the versions you have installed. Pick one out of them. I picked 7.0.5

I then ran

```
brew switch readline 7.0.5
```

The readline version got updated, and `psql` ran smoothly.

Comment: Also worked for me. psql was trying to load `libreadline.7.dylib`, but I was using readline 8.0.0. Switching from 8.0.0 to 7.0.5 solved the problem.

I expect that creating a symlink (as others have done) would also work, if I wanted to stay on 8.0.0. But having a newer version link to an older version is misleading and could potentially cause other issues.

Comment: How did you find this solution? I'm very impressed!

Comment: I tried the same, but got the following error: readline does not have a version "7.0.5" in the Cellar. I tried brew install 7.0.5 readline, but it shows the following error:  No available formula with the name "7.0.5" .@Dennis

Answer (score 23):

this worked for me

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.0.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib
```

Comment: This was my problem as well.  I did not use brew and was missing the sym link after latest update. Thanks!

Comment: Nice! My exact error complained about 6.2, my command is slightly different. The error was `dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.2.dylib`, so I used `ln -s /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.0.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.2.dylib`.

Answer (score 20):

The solution is to force the linking of readline again.

```
brew remove readline
brew install readline
brew link readline --force
```

Comment: relink didn't work for me, but reinstalling postgresql worked.

Answer (score 14):

It seems to me the problem is about update readline package.
postgres tryied to use /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib in my case. So i just created a symlink to existing version of library /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.8.dylib.

worked for me:

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.8.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib
```

Comment: This worked for me. I'm on psql version 9.6.3 and readline 8.

Comment: Admittedly this is a hacky way to go about fixing the issue, but I was running into this problem after some unrelated upgrades pushed my readline version from 7 to 8, and a full Postgres reinstall wasn't something I wanted to tackle right now. This is a small footprint solution and the risk of something impactful changing in readline seems small, so I'm going with this for now and moving on. Will report back if it causes any issues down the line.

Comment: Thanks for comment, I agree this issue. I had a lot of problems after updating to macos catalina, so I didn't want to digg into this issue and used the hack.

Answer (score 8):

None of those solutions worked for me; I had to run :

```
brew upgrade bash
```

from : https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/5799

Comment: in my el capitan after upgrade to 10.11.6 got this error too each time open terminal app, already solved by upgrading bash

Answer (score 6):

The answer above didn't work for me so I wanted to post what did eventually work. Based on a thread I found [here](https://github.com/staticfloat/homebrew-julia/issues/54), I had to uninstall readline and the install it again but from source.

```
brew uninstall readline
brew install --build-from-source readline
```

After that the psql error went away.

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue, and the key for me was to `reinstall` both `readline` and `postgres`. Once postgres was reinstalled, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to fix psql is update postgresql just running
`brew upgrade postgresql` since the newest version will use readline 7 version.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem when I updated readline to version 7 by accident. I uninstalled readline and brew remind me 6.3.8 is still installed. It seems that version 7 is not working with PSQL at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

I tried all these terminal commands and nothing worked so decided to fix it manually..

**Open finder** *and hit* **command+shift+g**

```
Go to this folder /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/
```

you should see multiple versions of these files

```
libreadline.6.dylib
libreadline.7.0.dylib
```

rename any of them to whichever library is not loaded

```
this is: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.2.dylib
mine was: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib
```

Comment: Works well for me

Answer (score 3):

I tried all the previews answers, and nothing worked. The only thing that really worked for me was:

`brew link postgresql`

Answer (score 3):

The following commands worked for me:

```
brew reinstall postgresql
brew postgresql-upgrade-database
```

Answer (score 2):

This had helped me:
uninstall all readline and postgresql

export CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/readline/include
export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib

and install posqtgresql

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution helpful

```
brew upgrade bash
```

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/5799

Answer (score 0):

You could try `brew doctor` and see what it says.

Possibly all you need is `brew link --overwrite bash`.

For me, I just upgraded brew since OS X EL Capitan had some security upgrade that affetcs my `/usr` folder. During the brew upgrade, the bash link is broken, and this is what `brew doctor` tells me.

So I just run `brew link --overwrite bash` and everything's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if you have anything else symlinked to `postgresql`. I had previously linked to the [postgres93](http://braumeister.org/repos/Homebrew/homebrew-versions/formula/postgresql93) package, which, as of May '17, is unsupported and has been removed. Removing that link and then relinking worked for me:

```
brew unlink postgresql93
brew link postgresql
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the correct answer did not fix the problem.

The problem started after running `brew doctor` and adding `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"` to my ~/.zshrc file.

Removing

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

from `~/.zshrc` got it solved.

Answer (score 0):

For some unknown reason, when this error popped up for the next version of Readline, my RVM seemed unable to locate the right one no matter how I symlinked it, throwing:

`Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib (LoadError)`

I ended up adding the gem `rb-readline` to my Gemfile and doing another `bundle install` and it started working.

I... just don't know.