# Mac psql/readline - Library not loaded

Tags: python, postgresql, command-line

I'm working on a Mac, Sierra 10.12.3, and I'm trying to access a PostgreSQL database via the `psql` command, but it threw the error

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/psql
Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

A day or two ago, I was working with someone and I needed to install pip, so I ran `brew install pip`, and it was all good. This is the first time I'm trying to run `psql` since then and I'm not certain that this has anything to do with my problem, but it seems likely since I haven't made any other changes.

Now I did a little detective work and found that if I went to `/usr/local/opt/` there was indeed a `readline` alias directory that pointed to `/usr/local/Cellar/readline/7.0.1` (version 7.0.1 also seeming to have gotten installed at some point - maybe as part of pip? Maybe I did it by mistake...) so it made some sense that the original error should be thrown. I changed the alias to point to `/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.3.8` and the error changed slightly:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/psql
Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib: stat() failed with errno=20
Abort trap: 6
```

So it seems like I'm getting *somewhere*, but still having an issue. If anyone can shed some light on a solution, I would be forever grateful.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488778/cant-run-psql-command-keep-getting-the-same-error - but answers the question much more succinctly, so well done :)

Comment: That's good news!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by simply running `brew switch readline 6.3.8`

Comment: I was getting the same error in a different context, trying to run `bash` commands via `subprocess.Popen()`, and `brew switch readline 6.3.8` worked for that as well.

Comment: That's awesome! Glad this helped - I was really frustrated.

Comment: Recently updated hombrew says: `Error: readline does not have a version "6.3.8" in the Cellar. Versions available: 7.0.1, 7.0.3, 7.0.3_1`. _sigh_

Comment: I don't know if this is a good idea, but I was able to get psql working with a symlink: `ln -s /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib`

Comment: This fixed helped me, thanks! But we need to be aware that previous registered brew readline version (in my case 7.0.5) was installed for some reasons before. After switch it is possible that some programs/libs which required previously installed version (in my case 7.0.5) will start to complain and stop working. If this is the case I would recommend doing fix like @dbenton suggested - to have both readline versions registered.

Comment: Thanks for helping to keep this advice up to date, @RobertLujo

Comment: The previous version no longer existed on my machine. In the end I had to reinstall postgres.

Answer (score 12):

Readline has been upgraded but you are still using an older psql from postgres. Upgrading postgres to a current version that uses the current readline fixed the problem for me:

`brew upgrade postgres`

Comment: This worked for me and seems like a much better solution than symlinking to fool it into using a newer version +1

Comment: In a realistic scenario, a postgres upgrade can cause for more issues than what is being trying to be solved. This should be recommended only with a sound warning

Comment: This worked for me. switch readline 6.3.8 didn't.
`brew switch readline 6.3.8`
`Error: readline does not have a version "6.3.8" in the Cellar.`
`readline installed versions: 8.0.1`

Comment: You can't switch to a version you don't already have installed.

Comment: You can, but it is messy. You have to unlink it, find the formula in Homebrew's repo and the exact commit you want to revert to.
Similar to what they do here for another formula: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/4547#issuecomment-423312200

Answer (score 11):

After I run `brew upgrade`, I also had this problem.

First, You need to confirm the version of the `readline` on your Mac.

In your situation, your old readline's version is 6.x. After upgrading, your readline was updated into 7.0.1. So you need to link your new readline.

These code might be helpful.

```sh
$ cd /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/  # cd to readline library
$ sudo ln -s libreadline.7.dylib libreadline.6.dylib  # change the link
```

I think the better way is to change the system readline link, but I don't know how to change.

Comment: Another day, another version. To get it to work, I had to `ln -s libreadline.7.dylib libreadline.8.0.dylib` This seems amazingly hacky. The most surprising thing is that it works.

Comment: @dland Thanks for this hacky fix. Worked for me. Though, I had to change the link parameters: `ln -s libreadline.8.0.dylib libreadline.7.dylib`.

Comment: If you have version 8 to 8.8 `ls -s libreadline.8.dylib libreadline.8.1.dylib`