# Heroku CLI psql command no longer works

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

All of my Heroku commands appear to be working except the one to get to a command line for my database.

Doing:

```
heroku pg:psql -a myapp
```

yields:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/psql
  Reason: image not found
```

I have had problems with this "readline" before. I'm not sure what it does, or why it is necessary, but how can I overcome this?

I'm running this on Mac OSX Sierra and I've installed Heroku with Homebrew.

heroku CLI version:

```
heroku/7.19.4 darwin-x64 node-v11.3.0
```

Answer (score 2):

[Readline](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) is a library that  "for use by applications that allow users to edit command lines as they are typed in".

For me, brew updated the version of readline from 7 (as seen in the error message above) to 8. You can confirm this by listing the contents of the directory that psql is looking in: `ls /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/`

I fixed this by upgrading postgres: `brew upgrade postgres`. Note that this will upgrade the version of Postgres running on your system. This worked seamlessly for me (I'm now running psgl 11.1 with a DB server of 9.6.8) but be aware of what you are upgrading and make sure things work afterwards.

I found this blog post helpful.

https://medium.com/@limichelle21/rails-5-troubleshooting-database-migration-from-sqlite3-to-postgresql-45bcb2ff0cb9

See also this SO: [Can't run psql command, keep getting the same error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488778/cant-run-psql-command-keep-getting-the-same-error/41476592#41476592)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this issue is caused by `psql` *not finding a necessary dependency it needs*, in this case `readline`.

If you don't have the `readline` library dependency I'd try installing `readline` with Homebrew:

```
brew install readline
```

However, if you already have `readline` library installed perhaps the image got messed up somewhere along the line so I'd try reinstalling and linking the library:

```
brew remove readline
brew install readline
brew link readline --force
```

Hopefully that helps!