# php -v returns dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib

Tags: php, macos

I was trying to install Valet and for a mistake I uninstall php from brew, now I reinstall php, if I go to a phpinfo() file on apache I can see

> PHP Version 7.1.23

but if I do `php -v` on console, or something other php command i get:

> dyld: Library not loaded:
>   /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib   Referenced from:
>   /usr/local/bin/php   Reason: image not found Abort trap: 6

Im on Mac Os Sierra

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488778/cant-run-psql-command-keep-getting-the-same-error may help you

Answer (score 14):

There's a couple of ways you could try to resolve this:

```
$ brew link readline
```

or perhaps:

```
$ brew link readline --force
```

If that doesn't work try:

```
$ cd /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/
$ ln -s libreadline.dylib libreadline.7.dylib
```

↳ [Github Discussion : libreadline (image not found)](https://gist.github.com/wbotelhos/46c37807c834ccb5bb406e426adfe347)

Comment: I had the same problem, the first part failed (needed `--force`), the second didn't solve the problem but the third one did.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I had php 5.4 installed, but an upgrade to php 7.3 worked for me.

```
brew install php@7.3
```

Then you'll likely need to add the new php version in your path. This basically means that when you load up your shell it knows where find the path to the files that you are using. For me, since I'm using zshrc that command is:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

For you, if you have all your path and aliases in bash profile then the command would be this instead:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Then, all you need to do is either source your zshrc or your bash_profile file, OR close that tab and open a new one. The source command basically says "hey, make sure you have an updated list of my aliases and path info". This naturally happens when you open a new shell, but you can force that with a command like:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

And then it worked for me. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ cd /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/
$ ln -s libreadline.dylib libreadline.7.dylib
```

Then :

```
brew unlink readline && brew link --force readline
```