# Rails 4 + Postgres: Randomly cannot connect to development server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am running Rails 4.2.2 and my postgres gem is 0.17.1 and everything was running fine yesterday but today when I opened the console and tried connecting to the database I saw this error:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

...then when I tried connecting to the database through running `psql`, I see the following:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/psql
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

As far I know I havent changed anythingsince yesterday so I'm not sure why this is happenning.  I tried adding `host: localhost` to my database.yml with no luck.  It may be worth noting when I try to connect to the DB using a program like PSequel, I see the following:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

**Has anyone seen this?**

Comment: restart you postgres server with: 
sudo service postgresql restart

Comment: it says `sudo: service: command not found`

Answer (score 0):

Neara's response to this post provided an answer for me: [PostgreSQL server won't stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930167/postgresql-server-wont-stop).

Basically had to run:

```
$ brew services list
$ brew services restart postgresql
```

They posted a workaround in case `services` cannot be found.