# Cannot kill Postgres process

Tags: macos, postgresql

I keep trying to kill a PostgreSQL process that is running on port 5432 to no avail. Whenever I type `sudo lsof -i :5432`, I see something like the below:

```
COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
postgres 587 postgres    4u  IPv6 0x218f97e9af5d0303      0t0  TCP *:postgresql (LISTEN)
postgres 587 postgres    5u  IPv4 0x218f97e9ae0f6c63      0t0  TCP *:postgresql (LISTEN)
```

I then try to kill the process 587 in this example with `sudo kill -9 587`, but then another process automatically restarts on the same port! I have tried killing it on activity monitor as well to no avail. Please help?

Thanks,
Laura

Comment: Do *not* use `kill -9` on the main PostgreSQL process (the *postmaster*). There is the danger that some PostgreSQL backend processes don't die imediately, and if a new postmaster is started before all the old processes are gone, you will end up with data corruption.

Comment: Laurenz is right. Killing a Postgres process from the command line is a bad idea. You need to properly shut down Postgres (e.g. `pg_ctl stop`)

Comment: I have the same problem, first I'm trying to kill a user with pg_terminate_backend, without result, then I do the pg_ctl stop -mf, but with no result, just when I kill a specific session with kill -9 dies, but my server restart

Answer (score 46):

If you installed postgres using brew, this command might be what you are looking for :

```
brew services stop postgres
```

Comment: Error: No available formula with the name "postgres". Did you mean postgrest or postgis?

Comment: @J.R.BobDobbs neither, I mean postgres

Answer (score 13):

I have 9.5 and 9.6 installed, so

> sudo su - postgres
>
> /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data stop

9.5 started ...

> /Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/data stop

Answer (score 11):

I had this issue and what I did to resolve it was first run

```
    brew services
```

to see a list of the services that home brew is running.  In my case the service was called 'postgresql@12' so I had to run

```
    brew services stop postgres@12
```

Comment: `brew services stop postgresql@15` is what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: it says service not found! my version is 14.

Comment: this worked for me

Answer (score 7):

list your postgres pid:

```
pg_ctl status -D /usr/local/var/postgres
pg_ctl: server is running (PID: 715)
```

force kill it..

```
kill -9 715
```

Answer (score 7):

Try to run this command:

```sh
sudo pkill -u postgres
```

Answer (score 2):

The process is restarting likely because it's spawned from a `launchd` daemon. You can try finding it and killing it through the `launchctl` command:

```
$ launchctl list
```

To kill a process you would:

```
$ launchctl kill
```

Comment: I found a few processes associated with Postgres but how do I kill them? I tried `launchctl kill 5660com.postgresapp.Postgres2MenuHelper.1184` but am not getting the syntax right :/

Comment: You have to use the signal name or number also... so `launchctl kill 9 ...` If the process spawns again you can also try `launchctl disable ...` and `launchctl unload`. In Terminal try doing `man launchctl` for help.

Answer (score 1):

my suffering:

```
sudo lsof -PiTCP -sTCP:LISTEN
```

[image]

> (replace 54011 with your PID)

```
ps -f -p 54011
```

[image]

```
pg_ctl status -D /opt/homebrew/var/postgres
```

[image]

```
 pg_ctl -D /opt/homebrew/var/postgres stop
```

but failed for me :(

[image]

---

my issue is with the launchctl of macos,
restarting the homebrew.mxcl.postgresql service,
but the suggested solutions for removing the service didn't work

```
launchctl bootout gui/501/homebrew.mxcl.postgres
```

only removes the service until the next login

and editing

```
vi /var/db/com.apple.xpc.launchd//disabled.501.plist
```

by removing the lines

```
<key>homebrew.mxcl.postgres</key>
<false/>
```

didn't effect anything.

So I finally removed the postgres binary of the deamon

```
 rm -r /opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@14
```

the service homebrew.mxcl.postgres is still there but no process.

---

the issue was in the LaunchAgent, so I removed the file

```
rm ~/Library/LaunchAgent/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

or in root

```
rm /Library/LaunchAgent/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

and

```
launchctl bootout gui/501/homebrew.mxcl.postgres
```

finally worked for me, no more  `homebrew.mxcl.postgres` entry in `launchctl list`, after relogin.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue trying to stop postgres. I was unable to use `pg_ctl stop`. I installed postgress using brew.

I eventually stumbled upon [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24135897/6749790) which solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

For those who's still struggling.

You can give it a try with the steps below

```
brew install pstree // enables you to see structuralized tree process
pstree | grep postgre
```

Remember the path of the parent task

```
Example)
/opt/homebrew/var/postgres
```

Then you remove the .pid file located at the directory of the parent task

```
rm -rf  <path of the parent task>/postmaster.pid
kill <PID of the parent task>
```

I hope it works for you too :)